# Correct processing of `$_POST`, following WordPress Coding Standards

Tags: post-meta, save-post, sanitization, coding-standards

## Background

I'm building a project that according to the specifications need to follow the [WordPress Coding Standards](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/). I am using **phpcs** to scan my code.

If I try to pass `$_POST`-data into a function without sanitizing it, I will get an error.

**What I do before my code:**

- Verify that this is actually a `POST` request by checking that `$_POST` is set.
- Verify that we have a value by checking if  `$_POST['faq_highlighted']` is set.
- Verify the nonce field using `wp_verify_nonce` to make sure that the request is from a valid source.

### The code

I noticed that depending on how i pass the posted value, the the error will behave differently, or disappear, even though there is no change to the functionality of the code.

###### Version 1

In this version, I check if `$_POST['faq_highlighted']` is set. If it is, I `update_post_meta` against the meta key `faq_highlighted` with the value of `$_POST['faq_highlighted']`.

```php
// Version 1.
if ( isset( $_POST['faq_highlighted'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'faq_highlighted', $_POST['faq_highlighted'] ); // Error on this line.
}
```

This rightfully gives me the following error on row 3:

> $_POST data not unslashed before sanitization. Use wp_unslash() or similar.
> Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable: $_POST['faq_highlighted']

###### Version 2

In this version, without any unslashing, escaping or sanitazion, I pass the value of `$_POST['faq_highlighted']` into a variable called `$value_of_post_faq_highlighted`. And I get the same error, but on that line.

This makes sense, as it's the use of a `$_POST` variable that is not *unslashed* that is triggering the error.

```php
// Version 2.
$value_of_post_faq_highlighted = $_POST['faq_highlighted']; // Error on this line.
if ( isset( $post_faq_highlighted ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'faq_highlighted', $post_faq_highlighted );
}
```

###### Version 3

This is where it gets strange. I'm now passing the whole `$_POST` into a variable called `$value_of_post`. There is still **no unslashing, escaping or sanitazion**, but `phpcs` does not give me any warnings.

```php
// Version 3 - No error!
$value_of_post = $_POST;
if ( isset( $value_of_post['faq_highlighted'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'faq_highlighted', $value_of_post['faq_highlighted'] );
}
```

## The question

As all the above mentioned blocks of code doing the exact same thing, and they all fail except for **version 3**, that I think should fail, **what would be the correct way of doing this?**

## My try on doing it correct.

###### Version 4 - My suggestion

This is what I have come to use. I first `wp_unslash` and then `sanitize_text_field`, and I get no errors, which makes sense, as this is the only version that resolves the two errors from the first version.

```php
// Version 4.
if ( isset( $_POST['faq_highlighted'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'faq_highlighted', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['faq_highlighted'] ) ) );
}
```

The reason I'm asking this question, is that **version 3** passed, just like **version 4**, I can see why **version 3** is not correct, and i *think* that **version 4** is the best way to do it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: version 3 may fail in future versions of PHP, and version 2 is outright broken and will cause PHP warnings when that POST parameter is missing

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why *version 3* might fail in future versions of php? I'm currently testing it for versions **7.4** and **8.0**. Regarding *warnings*, I have left out the code surrounding these lines, as I'm specifically trying to understand why version 3 is passing the tests, when it, to me, looks like it's doing nothing different from version 1 and 2. I updated the question with more background information, including the fact that i **1.** *verify that it's a post request*, **2.** *verify that `$_POST['faq_highlighted']` is set.*, and **3.** *verify the nonce*.

Comment: Because `$_POST` and the other super globals are special, assigning things to them or having them as a whole assigned as an array can be problematic. There's an RFC for PHP 8.1 to make some of these actions generate compile time fatal errors here https://wiki.php.net/rfc/restrict_globals_usage. Even if they were fine though, it should be considered very bad practice to do so. As for why v3 passes, that isn't because it's ok, that's a limitation of PHPCS, and fixing it isn't easy (but not impossible, you should raise a bug on the WPCS ticket). Remember we have a 1 question per question policy

Comment: But I'm not assigning values to any super globals. I'm only reading the values from them. I have read that RFC already, but it's about **modifying** super globals. I'm not even trying to modify **copies** of the super globals. It seems like you get lost in the syntax of the three examples I show as **wrong ways to do it**. My questino is **how** to do it correctly, and my suggestion is **version 4**. In that version I am not even making a copy of the `$_POST`. Thanks for clarification about **phpcs**, though, I'll open an issue there.

Comment: In v3 you're either copying or referencing the entire `$_POST` super-global into a variable, which is not good. The RFC is an example of the general attitude of super-globals such as `$_GLOBALS`, if we were in a non-WP community they may even flag the use of any super globals as bad practice and tell you to instead use `filter_input`, the main PHPCS contains sniffs to flag super global usage as a general anti-pattern. _Note that these comments are just comments, they are not attempts to answer your question, if they were, I would have written an answer not a comment._

Comment: @TomJNowell: okay, well, as you can see from my question, I was showing three ways that works to do it, that I believe are wrong, one of which passes the phpcs with the wpcs.

I know they are not correct, I explicitly wrote that in my post. They are there to show that I am aware that it is possible to solve it in these ways, and that they might pass phpcs even if they shouldn't. If you have any comments on how to improve **v4**, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: @FabianMossberg thanks so much for sharing. I have the exact same issue and was trying everything under the sun to first wp_unslash() and then esc_url_raw() for sanitization. And when I applied your fourth approach, it worked like a charm. I no longer was getting phpcs errors. Again, thanks so much!  And as for version 4, that one is good, because I read elsewhere that one should not directly access super globals such as $SERVER, even though the code words. They ARE special. By storing it as value of another variable, ok. Nothing should be overwritten or in conflict with other instances of it.